# Get Method JSON Response(String) Coding Complaint for key

Tags: ios, json, string, xcode, swift4

My ResponseString is as follows,

```
SUCCESS: 
{"code":200,"shop_detail":{"name":"dad","address":"556666"},
"shop_types : [{"name":"IT\/SOFTWARE","merchant_type":"office"}]}
```

My Get request code with headers is as follows,

```
func getProfileAPI() {
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Authorisation": AuthService.instance.tokenId ?? "",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json"
        ]
        print(headers)
        let scriptUrl = "http://haitch.igenuz.com/api/merchant/profile"

        if let url = URL(string: scriptUrl) {
            var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
            urlRequest.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.get.rawValue

            urlRequest.addValue(AuthService.instance.tokenId ?? "", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
            urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

            Alamofire.request(urlRequest)
                .responseString { response in
                    debugPrint(response)
                    print(response)
                    if let result = response.result.value //    getting the json value from the server
                    {
                        print(result)

                        let jsonData1 = result as NSString
                        print(jsonData1)
                        let name = jsonData1.object(forKey: "code") as! [AnyHashable: Any]
                        print(name)
                       // var data = jsonData1!["shop_detail"]?["name"] as? String

      } }
}
```

When I tried to get the value for "name" its getting'[<__NSCFString 0x7b40f400> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key code. Please guide me to get the values of name, address..?????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the **Response Handler** instead of **Response String Handler**:

> **Response Handler**
>
> The response handler does NOT evaluate any of the response data. It
>   merely forwards on all information directly from the URL session
>   delegate. It is the Alamofire equivalent of using cURL to execute a Request.

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let code: Int
    let shopDetail: ShopDetail
    let shopTypes: [ShopType]
}

struct ShopDetail: Codable {
    let name, address: String
}

struct ShopType: Codable {
    let name, merchantType: String
}
```

Also you can omit the coding keys from your struct declaration if you set your decoder `keyDecodingStrategy` (check [this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/52/swift-4-1-improves-codable-with-keydecodingstrategy)) to `.convertFromSnakeCase` as already mentioned in comments by @vadian:

---

```
Alamofire.request(urlRequest).response { response in
    guard 
       let data = response.data, 
       let json = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) 
    else { return }
    print("json:", json)
    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
        let root = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data)
        print(root.shopDetail.name)
        print(root.shopDetail.address)
        for shop in root.shopTypes {
            print(shop.name)
            print(shop.merchantType)
        }
    } catch { 
        print(error) 
    }            
}
```

For more information about encoding and decoding custom types you can read this [post](https://benscheirman.com/2017/06/swift-json/).

Comment: its getting json printed, now please help me in getting the values of shop detail printed for name/address and shoptype for name/merchant_type

Comment: Superb, it worked well, thank you very much for excellent coding @ Leo Dabus. This helped me to learn new things.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to convert the json string to data then decode it

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let code: Int
    let shopDetail: ShopDetail
    let shopTypes: [ShopType] 
}

struct ShopDetail: Codable {
    let name, address: String
}

struct ShopType: Codable {
    let name, merchantType: String 
}
```

Then

```
let jsonStr = result as! String
let dec = JSONDecoder()
dec.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
let res = try? dec.decode(Root.self,from:jsonStr.data(using:.utf8)!)
```

Note your str json may be invalid as you miss **"** after `shop_types` so make sure it looks like this

> {"code":200,"shop_detail":{"name":"dad","address":"556666"},
>   "shop_types" : [{"name":"IT/SOFTWARE","merchant_type":"office"}]}

Comment: Are you aware that you can omit all CodingKeys if you use the `.convertFromSnakeCase` key decoding strategy?

Comment: @vadian i agree , the reason is i no longer write the json myself as i have no time